# How to Return in python, reading multiple .xml files

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, function, return

I'm writing a script in Python that will go through a folder and Subfolder, reads only XML files with more than 100 files. If i hard code this code outside the function it reads all 100 XML files in temp0,  however if i put this code inside the function and use return, function always returns only one 1 file , I mean it reads only one file. Can anybody please explain why "return" works this way? Thanks in advance.

```
def raw_input(doc):
    for root, dirs, packs in doc:
        for files in packs:
            if files == 'abc.xml':
                filename = os.path.join(root, files)
                open_file = open(filename, 'r')
                perpX_ = open_file.read()
                # print(perpX_)
                outputX_ = re.compile('<test (.*?)</text>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(perpX_)
                temp0 = str("|".join(outputX_))
                #print(temp0)
                return temp0

doc=os.walk('./data/')
raw_input(doc)

temp0 = raw_input(doc)
print(temp0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` returns the function result, so as soon as `return` is reached, Python exits the function and takes the result of the expression next to `return` as an output of a function.

You've got your `return` inside a `for` loop, which means that it will be reached on every iteration, but Python interpreter assumes `temp0` to be the final result of your function call, so it quits.

You could return multiple values in a list, e.g., like this:

```py
def raw_input(doc):
    result = []    # this is where your output will be aggregated
    for root, dirs, packs in doc:
        for files in packs:
            if files == 'abc.xml':
                filename = os.path.join(root, files)
                open_file = open(filename, 'r')
                perpX_ = open_file.read()
                # print(perpX_)
                outputX_ = re.compile('<test (.*?)</text>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(perpX_)
                # We append the output for current file to the list
                result.append(str("|".join(outputX_)))
    # And now we return our string, at the end of the function.
    # AFTER the for loops
    return '|'.join(result)

doc=os.walk('./data/')

temp0 = raw_input(doc)
print(temp0)
```

This way, you'll get your outputs as a single string.

Also, there's such a thing as `generator`. A [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is an object that can be iterated. You can make your code evaluate lazily (on demand):

```py
# now raw_input is a generator
def raw_input(doc):
    # we don't need a storage now
    for root, dirs, packs in doc:
        for files in packs:
            if files == 'abc.xml':
                filename = os.path.join(root, files)
                open_file = open(filename, 'r')
                perpX_ = open_file.read()
                outputX_ = re.compile('<test (.*?)</text>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(perpX_)
                # now we yield current value and function temporary stops its evaluation
                yield str("|".join(outputX_))

doc=os.walk('./data/')
results = raw_input(doc)
# now results is a generator. It is not evaluated yet
# you can get first output like this:
first_out = next(results)
# and then the second:
second_out = next(results)
# or iterate over it, just like over a casual list:
for res in results:
    print(res)
# note that it will iterate only over next values
# (excluding first and second ones, since it doesn't have access to them anymore)

# and now res is empty (we've reached the end of generator)
```

Comment: This Method doesn't work, and i dont want to put read files into list as well it should be in String type.

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda, alright, I'll edit it so that a `str` is returned.

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda, I've edited the first option to return a single string. If it "doesn't work", then provide the exceptions it's raising or the result of a function